# How to forbid triggering input method when the input method hotkey is pressed in QLineEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I was developing a Windows desktop app. I want to implement a widget **based on QLineEdit**, which receive hotkey setting for my Application, so the widget **should not trigger input method** when the corresponding hotkey, such as the combination Ctrl+Shift is pressed.

Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

In Qt there is similar widget QKeySequenceEdit. (it is looks like QLineEdit, but has Press shortcut word)

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html

This widget available in Qt Designer too, Input Widgets - Key sequence Edit.

Also, if you press Ctrl+V for exampe, widget catch this hotkey (doesn't paste)

Example of usage

```
void MainWindow::on_keySequenceEdit_editingFinished()
{
    QKeySequence key;
    key = ui->keySequenceEdit->keySequence();
    qDebug() << key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all the same although my qt edition is 4.7.1 for some reason.